# How to get a reference to the control being rendered from a custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to hook up `OnFling` to a `TextCell` using Xamarin.Forms. I believe I've hooked the event up correctly but I'm unsure how to pass a reference of the control to the listener object?

I essentially want to do the following:

```
public class MyTextCell : TextCell
{
    public void UserSwiped (SwipeDirection direction)
    {
        //Do Foo...
    }
}

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MyTextCell), typeof(MyTextCellRenderer))]
public class MyTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    private readonly MyTextCellListener _listener;
    private readonly GestureDetector _detector;

    public MyTextCellRenderer ()
    {
        _listener = new MyTextCellListener (MyTextCell); //Here I need to get the reference to the MyTextCell that the renderer is rendering...
        _detector = new GestureDetector (_listener);
    }
}

public class BincTextCellListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    public MyTextCellListener(MyTextCell cell)
    {
         Cell = cell;
    }

    MyTextCell Cell {get; set; }

    public override bool OnFling (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        Cell.UserSwiped(SwipedDirection.SomeDirection);
    }
}
```

[This post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24242/calling-a-custom-method-on-a-custom-renderer) suggests that I should be able to get the reference from the `NewElement` object when you override `OnElementChanged()`. However, `TextCellRenderer` does not have that method to override. (It's equivalent is `GetCellCore()`, but that doesn't hold a property the `NewElement` either?)

Is anyone able to advise how to access the `MyTextCell` object from the `MyTextCellRenderer`?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of GetCellCore is a Xamarin.Forms.Cell, which you should be able to cast to your custom MyTextCell

```
protected override View GetCellCore (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
```